# Destiny2 API - POST Transfer Item always return DestinyItemNotFound

Tags: python, api

first, sorry for my bad english.

I'm working for make Destiny2 Item Manager Application - not for commercial, just Toy Proejct.
Problem is, when I send POST request to bungie.net, They're response is always DestinyItemNotFound, errorcode 500.
I've tried many things like checking parameters, or correcting hashes, or try to transfer from vault, but any of it doesn't work

here's my python code, and I guarantee that parameters are not the cause of problem - I checked it thousand times.

```
headers = {
    "X-API-Key": api_key,
    "Authorization": f'Bearer {access_token}'
}



def post_transfer_item(itemHash, Instance_id, transfer_to_vault, character_id, membership_type):

    global headers
    url = f'{API_ROOT_PATH}/Destiny2/Actions/Items/TransferItem/'

    data = {
     "DestinyItemTransferRequest": json.dumps(
         {
            'itemReferenceHash': int(itemHash),
            'stackSize': 1,
            'transferToVault': transfer_to_vault,
            'itemId': int(Instance_id),
            'characterId': int(character_id),
            'membershipType': int(membership_type.value)
         }
     )
    }

    api_call = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
    return json.loads(api_call.text)
```

and I call it like this:

```
resp = [post_transfer_item(vault[0]['itemHash'], vault[0]['InstanceID'], False, user.character_ids[0], user.membership_type)]
```

that 'itemHash' and 'InstanceID' is from API response, so that's not the problem